# OWL Carousel Fade Transition Speed

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Am using OWL v2.0 and load animate.css to support 'fadeIn' and 'fadeOut', but having difficulty in trying to extend the transition time of the fade between slide 1 and slide 2. Seems to a constant 1 second or so whatever I try.

```
        owl.owlCarousel({
            nav: false, // Show next and prev buttons 
            items: 1,
            smartSpeed: 10000,
            dotsSpeed: 1000,
            dragEndSpeed: 1000,
            singleItem: true,
            animateIn: 'fadeIn',
            animateOut: 'fadeOut',
            pagination: false,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 5000,
            autoplayHoverPause: false,
            loop: true,
            afterAction: function (el) {
                //remove class active
                this
                    .$owlItems
                    .removeClass('active')

                //add class active
                this
                    .$owlItems //owl internal $ object containing items
                    .eq(this.currentItem + 1)
                    .addClass('active')
            }
        });
```

Any ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transition duration is in the owl.carousel.css file. At line 103 you should have:

```
.owl-carousel .animated { 
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both; }
```

try changing the animation-duration of 1000ms to your desired duration.

Comment: Why would they even add a `speed` option if it they hardcode the CSS3 animation like that, seriously OWL...

Comment: There's a typo in your class name, `.owl-caraousel` -> `.owl-carousel`

Answer (score 0):

That's the autoplayTimeout you are talking about. No need to override the css.

Change the autoplayTimeout to 1000 when you want that the next slide will happen after 1 sec.
Change the autoplaySpeed to 2000, when you want that that slide has a slide effect that takes up 2 sec.
So when setting this: the first slide take 2 sec of duration when sliding. After 1 sec, the next will slide for 2sec, and so on...